# Show content of a window on two screens

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

When I'm giving a talk, I frequently project something (most of the time it's a browser window, but not always) on a screen that is behind me while at the same time have notes of what I'm presenting on the main laptop screen. This means that I would like to have a copy of what is on the projected screen on the main screen as well to be able to control the content and see what the audience is seeing.

If I choose to mirror the screens my notes would show on the projected screen - something which I do not want.

Is there a way to place a copy of one window on the projected screen, while having the same content on my laptop?

Comment: Good question. Would work immediately in tiling window manager i3. There, different screens are different workspaces, so setting "Always on visible workspaces" would do the trick there.

Comment: You can extend the screen to the right (or left), and then use GStreamer to [mirror](https://superuser.com/a/1378465/) a window and move the mirrored window to that screen.

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I found is using OBS Studio. To get it working:

1. Open the window you want to project on the main screen and resize it so it is roughly the same aspect ratio of the second screen.
2. Open OBS Studio on main screen, create a new scene, add a window capture source and configure it to show the desired window.
3. From the OBS system tray icon on top, choose "Fullscreen projector (preview)" and select the second monitor.

It's a bit of an overkill of use a powerful program like OBS to mirror a window, but this is the only solution I found so far. However, using OBS gives you the possibility of, not only to mirror one window, but to configure what you project on the second screen (like having more than one window for example) by setting up your scene as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue and I found a slightly different solution than To Do had by using https://meet.jit.si which is a free, secure, online digital conference platform.

How I use it:

- Start a new conference with a long and very random key to get additional security by obfuscation. https://meet.jit.si/thisIsmystrangeandunbreakablecode23423
- Share your main screen.
- Mute the mic and stop the camera, you will not use it.
- In the participant pane click on the shared screen and then click on: 
  **Show me what I'm sharing**.
- Minimize the participant pane with the `>` button.
- Right click on the browser window top and select **Always on top**
- Resize the window to your liking
- Move the window to position, you can use [super] + mouse to move the window by clicking and dragging anywhere on the window. I use this trick to move the top of the browser window out of the screen.
- Finally on the big screen hide the sharing notification.

A positive side effect is that your participants can join the meeting and view the presentation locally, maybe with a slightly easier meeting code.

If you do not want to use the online version there is a possibility to run jit.si locally but that is another story.